# Duplicate Tuples in two different ways

Tags: function-construction, tuples

Writing:

```
n = 3;
Tuples[{"min", "MAX"}, n]
```

I get:

> {{"min", "min", "min"}, {"min", "min", "MAX"}, {"min", "MAX", "min"}, {"min", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"MAX", "min", "min"}, {"MAX", "min","MAX"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "min"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "MAX"}}

One way to duplicate this function is to fill in this table *by columns*. In fact, writing:

```
tuples = ConstantArray[0, {2^n, n}];
flag = 1;
For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
    For[i = 1, i <= 2^n, i++,
        If[flag == 1,
           tuples = ReplacePart[tuples, {i, j} -> "min"],
           tuples = ReplacePart[tuples, {i, j} -> "MAX"]
          ];
        If[Mod[i, 2^(n - j)] == 0, flag = flag + 1];
        If[flag > 2, flag = 1]
       ]
   ];
tuples
```

I get:

> {{"min", "min", "min"}, {"min", "min", "MAX"}, {"min", "MAX", "min"}, {"min", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"MAX", "min", "min"}, {"MAX", "min","MAX"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "min"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "MAX"}}

Now I would like to duplicate this function by filling in this table *by rows*. My first approach is the following:

```
tuples = ConstantArray[0, {2^n, n}];
For[i = 1, i <= 2^n, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
        If[2^(j - 1) <= i <= 2^n/2^j,
           tuples = ReplacePart[tuples, {i, j} -> "min"],
           tuples = ReplacePart[tuples, {i, j} -> "MAX"]
          ]
       ]
   ];
tuples
```

which offers only the first correct column:

> {{"min", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"min", "min", "MAX"}, {"min", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"min", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"MAX", "MAX","MAX"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "MAX"}}

Any idea to correct this code? Thanks!

Comment: Why does the order in which you fill the matrix matter?

Comment: Mathematica stores matrices in row-order, so proceeding by rows will always be more efficient than proceeding be columns. Trying to force a computation into column-order will only slow the computation down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noticing  that going row-by-row, we're essentially counting in binary (with `"min"` as `0` and `"MAX"` as `1`), we see that we can use `BitAnd[i - 1, 2^(n - j)] == 0` as condition:

```
n = 3;

tuples = ConstantArray[0, {2^n, n}];
For[i = 1, i <= 2^n, i++, 
 For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
  If[BitAnd[i - 1, 2^(n - j)] == 0, 
   tuples = ReplacePart[tuples, {i, j} -> "min"],
   tuples = ReplacePart[tuples, {i, j} -> "MAX"]
   ]
 ]
];
tuples
(* {{"min", "min", "min"}, {"min", "min", "MAX"}, {"min", "MAX", "min"}, 
    {"min", "MAX", "MAX"}, {"MAX", "min", "min"}, {"MAX", "min", "MAX"},
    {"MAX", "MAX", "min"}, {"MAX", "MAX", "MAX"}} *)
```

Or, more concise:

```
tuples = ConstantArray[0, {2^n, n}];
Do[
  tuples = ReplacePart[
    tuples,
    {i, j} -> If[BitAnd[i - 1, 2^(n - j)] == 0, "min", "MAX"]
    ],
  {i, 2^n},
  {j, n}
  ];
tuples
(* same output *)
```

The condition works by checking the $(n-j)$-th bit of $i-1$ using [`BitAnd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitAnd.html):

- $n-j$ instead of e.g. $j$ because the zeroth bit is the $n$-th column, and the $n-1$-th bit is the first column
- The $-1$ in $i-1$ is needed since row indices start at $1$, but the counting starts at $0$

*Note:* Since the condition is completely stateless (i.e. there is no `flag` variable or similar), we can simply swap the iteration indices to change the filling order:

```
tuples = ConstantArray[0, {2^n, n}];
Do[
  tuples = ReplacePart[
    tuples,
    {i, j} -> If[BitAnd[i - 1, 2^(n - j)] == 0, "min", "MAX"]
    ],
  {j, n},
  {i, 2^n}
  ];
tuples
(* same output *)
```

Comment: `BitAnd` is essentially the bit wise AND operator from most other languages (e.g. `&` in C and related languages). Also, what exactly do you mean by "not pre-packaged in some environments"?

Comment: Out of curiosity: can you give an example of such a language without `BitAnd` equivalent?

Comment: I think you don't need to worry about this particular operator - I think I have yet to come across a language without bit wise operators

Answer (score 3):

Lukes answer is excellent but it can be improved. This version is faster as well as more concise.

```
n = 3;
tuples = ConstantArray[0, {2^n, n}];
Do[
  tuples[[i, j]] = If[BitAnd[i - 1, 2^(n - j)] == 0, "min", "MAX"], 
  {j, n}, {i, 2^n}];
tuples // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Your For-loop solution can also be improved by applying the same ideas.

```
flag = 0;
Do[
  If[flag == 0, tuples[[i, j]] = "min", tuples[[i, j]] = "MAX"]; 
  If[Mod[i, 2^(n - j)] == 0, flag = Mod[flag + 1, 2]],
  {j, n}, {i, 2^n}];
```